# Can't set JTree nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree, intellij-plugin

Working on a IntelliJ Platform plugin and just trying to set the nodes in a JTree, but I can't get it to work.

[image]

This is the JTree in the form, and here is the code:

```
public class MyToolWindow {

  private JTree tree1;
  private JPanel myToolWindowContent;

  public MyToolWindow(ToolWindow toolWindow) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("The Java Series");
    //createNodes(top);
    tree1 = new JTree(top);
  }

  public JPanel getContent() {
    return myToolWindowContent;
  }
```

When I run it, all I get is the boilerplate Tree:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me:

[image]

I checked the "Custom Create" box, and then implemented the `createUIComponents` method in the code:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    treeModel.setAsksAllowsChildren(true);
    tree1 = new JTree(treeModel);
  }
```

That gets me a base JTree configured however I need it. Then when my ToolWindow loads I can access the tree like this:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree1.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)model.getRoot();
root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("another_child"));
model.reload(root);
```

Not 100% sure that is the best practice way, but its working for me.